# Criar Classe de Login javascript & php (AJAX)

Tags: php, javascript

Pessoal tenho uma grande duvida em relação ao es6 do javascript pra criar uma classe de login, minha intenção era organizar mais o código só que nao sei por onde começar :p, peço desculpas pela minha falta de conhecimento sobre o assunto mais tento procurar aqui uma luz.

estou usando esse padrão para criar minhas funções usando o ajax do jquery & php; .

```
var LOGIN;

LOGIN = {

Auth: function () { Aqui o código }
Logoff: function () { Aqui o código }

}
LOGIN.Auth();
```

Comment: cole os outros códigos, pois conforme sua pergunta são javascript + ajax + php. Aqui nós auxiliamos e não criamos e lhe fornecemos o código pronto que precisa, respondemos dúvidas.

Comment: Você comentou sobre classe JS, mas o trecho que postou não é uma, o que ficou bastante confuso. Também cita PHP, mas não descreve o que ele faz: você possui alguma API no PHP de gerenciamento de acesso? Se sim, adicione seus detalhes na pergunta

Comment: peço desculpas amigo o que eu queria dizer e se tem como melhorar a modularizarão do código era isso que queria dizer.